# Write application message to a Language file

Tags: android

Can we place the messages shown in Toast in the whole application to a particular language file..
 so that if we need to edit a message , we can edit in that particular file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact it's the prefered way for storing the strings shown all over the application (even in text labels and such) because this allows for easy localization.

You should take a look at [this how-to](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/49733.aspx)